# Angular material, md-grid-tile

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Can someone help me to make this look a little bit better.

[image]

I have three columns and in the first one I need to put some subtitles and underneath them three rows.In the other two rows I want to add some data but it needs to be aligned with the rows. So for example I have "Well defined Mass" and
underneath it I have "Undetected", "Misinterpreted" and then I have "Total". In the middle column I mo going to add the data but it needs to be aligned with "Undetected", "Misinterpreted" and "Total". Where Well defined mass is needs to be empty.

```
<div>

<md-toolbar layout-align="center center">
    <span>False Negative Responses</span>
</md-toolbar>
<div style="margin:15px">
    <md-grid-list md-cols="3" md-row-height="50px">

        <md-grid-tile><h4>Radiographic Feature Type</h4></md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile><h4>You: Mean % Missed Feature</h4></md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile><h4>ALL PARTICIPANTS: % Missed Feature</h4></md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <h4>Well defined mass</h4>
                <p>Undetected</p>
                <p>Misinterpreted</p>
                <p>Total</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </div>

        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <h4>Ill defined mass</h4>
                <p>Undetected</p>
                <p>Misinterpreted</p>
                <p>Total</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>

            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <h4>Spiculate defined mass</h4>
                <p>Undetected</p>
                <p>Misinterpreted</p>
                <p>Total</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>

            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <h4>Architectural Distortion</h4>
                <p>Undetected</p>
                <p>Misinterpreted</p>
                <p>Total</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>

            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>

            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <h4>Asymmetry</h4>
                <p>Undetected</p>
                <p>Misinterpreted</p>
                <p>Total</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>

            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <h4>Calcification</h4>
                <p>Undetected</p>
                <p>Misinterpreted</p>
                <p>Total</p>
            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
            </div>

        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            <div layout="column" layout-align="center" style="padding: 10px;">
                <p>HI</p>
                <p>Hi</p>
                <p>Hi</p>

            </div>
        </md-grid-tile>


    </md-grid-list>


</div>
```

This is my code.

Comment: where is the `md-grid-list`?

Comment: its there I just edited it